# Null pointer exception in Liquibase core

Tags: oracle, liquibase

I am getting a null pointer issue in liquibase core. It started in 3.7.x onward. My code is working fine with 3.6.3 core jar. I was trying to create table in oracle DB by comparing change logs.

```
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at liquibase.changelog.ChangeSet.isInheritableIgnore(ChangeSet.java:900) ~[liquibase-core-4.9.0.jar:?]
    at liquibase.changelog.filter.IgnoreChangeSetFilter.accepts(IgnoreChangeSetFilter.java:11) ~[liquibase-core-4.9.0.jar:?]
    at liquibase.changelog.ChangeLogIterator$2.run(ChangeLogIterator.java:79) ~[liquibase-core-4.9.0.jar:?]
    at liquibase.Scope.lambda$child$0(Scope.java:180) ~[liquibase-core-4.9.0.jar:?]
    at liquibase.Scope.child(Scope.java:189) ~[liquibase-core-4.9.0.jar:?]
    at liquibase.Scope.child(Scope.java:179) ~[liquibase-core-4.9.0.jar:?]
    at liquibase.Scope.child(Scope.java:158) ~[liquibase-core-4.9.0.jar:?]
    at liquibase.Scope.child(Scope.java:243) ~[liquibase-core-4.9.0.jar:?]
    at liquibase.Scope.child(Scope.java:247) ~[liquibase-core-4.9.0.jar:?]
    at liquibase.changelog.ChangeLogIterator.run(ChangeLogIterator.java:65) ~[liquibase-core-4.9.0.jar:?]
    ... 8 more
```

Comment: I found same kind of issue in postgresql also.  i am also getting Error executing SQL SELECT COUNT(*) FROM DATABASECHANGELOG: ORA-00942: table or view does not exist. this cause null pointer issue at  public boolean isInheritableIgnore() {
        DatabaseChangeLog changeLog = this.getChangeLog();
        return changeLog.isIncludeIgnore();   // HERE 
    }     https://forum.liquibase.org/t/liquibase-maven-plugin-cannot-find-the-databasechangelog-table-postgresql/4415/7

Comment: You can create a bug report for the team to investigate here: https://www.liquibase.org/community/contribute/report-bugs

Comment: same error=====>  Cannot invoke "liquibase.changelog.DatabaseChangeLog.isIncludeIgnore()" because "changeLog" is null.